# Jscript syntax error - code 800A03EA - Microsoft JScript compilation - Sawtooth Supply Chain - Windows 10

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, windows-10, jscript, hyperledger-sawtooth

trying to setup sawtooth supply chain using docker-composer up command but am getting the following error. Running on Windows 10 laptop with version 0.10.1. 
I have downloaded the files from https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain and followed the readme.md file for setup.

When I lookup the file '/sawtooth-supply-chain/ledger_sync/index.js' i get a javascript syntax error with code 800A03EA with Source as Microsoft JScript compilation error.
Can someone please help?

```
`supply-ledger-sync | module.js:549
supply-ledger-sync | throw err;
supply-ledger-sync | ^
supply-ledger-sync |
supply-ledger-sync | Error: Cannot find module '/sawtooth-supply-chain/ledger_sync/index.js'
supply-ledger-sync | at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
supply-ledger-sync | at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
supply-ledger-sync | at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
supply-ledger-sync | at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
supply-ledger-sync | at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
supply-shell | npm ERR! path /sawtooth-supply-chain/asset_client/package.json
supply-shell | npm ERR! code ENOENT
supply-shell | npm ERR! errno -2
supply-shell | npm ERR! syscall open
supply-rethink | Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
supply-server | module.js:549
supply-server | throw err;
supply-server | ^
supply-server |
supply-server | Error: Cannot find module '/sawtooth-supply-chain/server/index.js'
supply-server | at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
supply-server | at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
supply-server | at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
supply-server | at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
supply-server | at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
supply-rethink | Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080
supply-shell | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/sawtooth-supply-chain/asset_client/package.json'
supply-shell | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
supply-shell | npm ERR! enoent'
```

The code in index.js at /sawtooth-supply-chain/server/index.js is as below:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2017 Intel Corporation
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const db = require('./db')
const blockchain = require('./blockchain')
const protos = require('./blockchain/protos')
const api = require('./api')
const config = require('./system/config')

const PORT = config.PORT
const app = express()

Promise.all([
  db.connect(),
  protos.compile(),
  blockchain.connect()
])
  .then(() => {
    app.use('/', api)
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Supply Chain Server listening on port ${PORT}`)
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err.message))
```

Regards
Ganesh Bhat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the solution to the above, but you'll find it much easier if you install a VM such as VirtualBox and then run Sawtooth with Docker and docker-compose in VirtualBox.

Comment: I have done what you are suggesting as the steps to install sawtooth requires a need to install VM and docker. link here: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/app_developers_guide/docker.html

Comment: The MS JS error implies it's running on MS Windows, not Ubuntu Linux.  I like these installation instructions better:
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/installing_sawtooth.html
Basically, install and run on the VirtualBox VM instance (Ubuntu Linux).  You can install Docker and docker-compose on Ubuntu and that's easier than installing on Ubuntu directly.

Answer (score 1):

I Googled in on this today too. *JScript* / *Microsoft Windows Based Script Host* was unable to cope with ECMAScript type syntax or Regex functionality.

For me, I found it was likely down to using keywords such as:

- `let`.
- `forEach`
- `exec`

(last two with a regex matcher).

BTW: Code was an amalgamation of:

- what [regex101](https://regex101.com/) generates for the JavaScript, and
- Wscript stuff from something like [this](https://rpaknowledge.com/automation-anywhere-the-run-script-command/).

I ended up ditching the JavaScript and using VBScript instead, as I was trying to call Script code for regexes that contained multiple groups from Automation Anywhere and content with multiple results in one shot.